# How to create columns from specific row in Tableau

Tags: tableau-desktop

I'm practising my Tableau - well learning - skills and trying to visualise an old csv dataset.

I want to crop the top two rows and assign the columns to the top row. How do I do that?

I'd then like to filter out the data rows in two ways. One would be to just select regional totals, and a second filter by local authority. Need to learn as these are basics in Pandas.

```
Table as_16_q: Asylum seekers in receipt of Section 95 support, by local authority, as at end of quarter                        
Back to contents                        
Quarter Region                   Local Authority    Total supported under Section 95    In receipt of subsistence only  In dispersed accommodation  Disbenefited


 2003 Q4    *Total                   *Total             80,123                    30,362                            47,148                          2,613

2003 Q4     East Midlands *Total     East Midlands      4,524   1,027                           3,465                       32
2003 Q4     East of England *Total   East of England    1,944   1,216                           655                         73
2003 Q4     London  *Total           London             24,916  22,017                          746                         2,153
2003 Q4     North East  *Total           North East         5,172   216 
                        4,930                       26
```

...

And then on to local authorities...

```
    2003 Q4     Scotland                 Aberdeen           17      
17                              0                           0
    2003 Q4     East Midlands            Amber Valley       1        1                              0                           0
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the [Data Interpreter](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/data_interpreter.htm) for cropping the top rows and [Data Source filters](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/filtering_datasource.htm) for reducing the amount of data in the data source.